# nuxeo mvn compilation issue

Tags: maven, nuxeo

I am trying to compile nuxeo using as a guide the documentation described here: http://doc.nuxeo.com/display/public/CORG/Getting+the+Nuxeo+source+code

However I am not able to run the following command sucessfully: mvn -DskipTests install -Paddons

I have no idea what can be wrong. Here are the details of my workstation:

java -version
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.2.1 (ea8b2b07643dbb1b84b6d16e1f08391b666bc1e9; 2014-02-14T17:37:52+00:00)
Maven home: C:\Maven\bin..
Java version: 1.7.0_04, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\jdk1.7.0_04\jre
Default locale: pt_PT, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile
>   (default-testCompile) on project
>   nuxeo-annot-gwt: Compilation failure
>   [ERROR] An unknown compilation problem
>   occurred [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException:
>   Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile
>   (default-testCompile) on project
>   nuxeo-annot-gwt: Compilation failure
>   An unknown compilation problem
>   occurred
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
>     at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
> ```
>
> Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
>           at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
>   Caused by:
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException:
>   Compilation failure An unknown
>   compilation problem occurred
>
> ```
>     at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:858)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.TestCompilerMojo.execute(TestCompilerMojo.java:152)
>     at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
>     at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
>     ... 19 more [ERROR] [ERROR] [ERROR] For more information about the
> ```
>
> errors and possible solutions, please
>   read the following articles: [ERROR]
>   [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
>   [ERROR] [ERROR] After correcting the
>   problems, you can resume the build
>   with the command [ERROR]   mvn 
>   -rf :nuxeo-annot-gwt

The error has almost no information, so I am lost for a solution.

Comment: "An unknown compilation problem occurred". This might be a problem with the javac executable. Try to run the command with debug-logging ( adding `--debug` or `-X` ), which could expose the root cause.

Comment: Hi Robert that is the log with -X. Hence the above trace log

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems Maven is not using the same Java as the one you configured in your environment:

```
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java version: 1.7.0_04, vendor: Oracle Corporation
```

That may result in an "unknown compilation problem".

Check your environment variables `M2_HOME`, `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` to make sure the Maven and Java paths are consistent between them.

If the issue is still present, then try to run "`mvn clean install -DskipTests -pl :nuxeo-annot-gwt -X`" and share the output.

Comment: I installed a new JDK and cleaned up the environment variables, that worked. Thanks!